# Non-unique geocoding in ggmap

Tags: r, geocoding, ggmap

Hi there and happy saturday.

I have a dataset with streets names and would like to geocode them. However, the streets are not unique: there are multiple streets with the same name.

I would like to return a the lng/lat of all potential streets.

Any ideas? :)